# Python selenium chrome driver SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, macos, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

When trying to run undetected-chromedriver I was running into the following error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using macOS go to Macintosh HD > Applications > Python3.9 folder (or whatever version of python you're using) > double click on "Install Certificates.command" file.

Comment: What about the situation for non-mac, like for docker ubuntu based container? I tried having the `pip install --upgrade certify` as well.

Answer (score 0):

### From OP's posted time 2 yrs ago, I was still facing this until the below solution solved for me.

I faced this issue with the chromedriver_autoinstaller library on my docker based of ubuntu image. The below lines of code only solved my problem.

Before listing that solution, i wanted to mention that i used the below command as well in my dockerfile

```
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade certify
```

But this alone did not help. So i explored and found the below two lines in the python file solved the error. This is a hacking solution only, but since my need is to have this run on docker container and knowing the application to access via selenium and its boundary, with other security control measures taken, I went with this.

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```